# change keyboard sign shortcut

Tags: terminal, mac, keyboard

my keyboard has randomly changes the cmnd2 shortcut from @  to changing to the second tab open. until now it was all working perfectly. the computer is quite old but is working perfectly and I do remember something similar happening to me previously and can't seem to recall how I changes it back and cannot find any answer that is quite it online. does someone have any knowlege of what should I do?

Comment: What is your input language? On English keyboards at least, Shift/2 should be @, not Cmd/2. Cmd/number is the standard shortcut to 'switch to tab number'.

Comment: cmnd is not used for characters.  @ is normally at Shift 2 unless you are using British PC layout, when it is over at the right edge at Shift '  .